# Time Series fill NAs for big time gaps (more than a month) based on related data from other years

Tags: python, time-series, interpolation, fillna, merging-data

I have a Time Series dataset with daily observations for the period 2015-2022.
However, years 2015-2018 have data only for half year: from January to June (all days from July to December are NAs). But years 2019-2022 have date for all months and all days.
I would like to fill all NA for years with missing months based on data from 2019-2022. In other words, I would like to calculate mean values for each day of missing months based on existing values for other years. Then, I need to fill NA's with corresponding calculated means.

Here is the code for creating a DataFrame which represent my dataset and existing problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(1)

rows,cols = 1000,3 # dataframe with 1000 rows, each raw represents data for one day (from 1st January 2019 to 26th September 2021)
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='D') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c'], index=tidx) #there are 3 columns with data
date_list =pd.date_range(start='2019-07-01', end='2019-08-31') 
df[df.index.isin(date_list)] = np.nan #July and August have missing data for all days in 2019 year, but 2020 and 2021 have data for these months

print (df)
```

In simulated df presented above, I need to fill NAs for July and August of 2019 with **mean values** calculated for each day of these months based on corresponding data which are present for 2020 and 2021.
I have tried various interpolation methods provided by pandas library, but results are very bad, because time periods with missing data are pretty big.

Comment: The question is not clear.  option a) for '2019-07-02' you want to calculate the mean values between '2020-07-02' and '2020-07-02'. Option b) the mean of '2020-07-01' -'2020-08-31' and '2021-07-01', end='2021-08-31'?

Comment: option a): I want to replace NAs on 2019-07-02  with mean values calculated for data on 2020-07-02 and 2021-07-02 and then the same for following days in July and August

Comment: considering your feedback I have made an answer. Let me know if is it clear

Comment: It is all clear, it solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several steps to do this

- Step 1 find days of the year that values are missing
- Step 2 find the average values for the years 2020 and 2021 for the days of 2019 with missing values. This can easily be done using groupby and mean as aggregation function
- step 3 fill the nan with the new values

```py
# step 1
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df["date_year"] = df.timestamp.dt.dayofyear
mising_days = df[df.a.isna()]["date_year"].to_list()

# step 2
res = df[df.date_year.isin(mising_days)].groupby("date_year").mean()

# step 3
df.loc[df.a.isna(), ["a", "b", "c"]] = res.values
df.drop(["timestamp", "date_year"], axis=1) # drop values used for the calculation
```